# Merge features based on column value

Tags: postgis

I have a table `planet_osm_roads`. The table has one column `ref` that indicates the code of the road.

Let's say that I have a road coded 'AA1' which is represented by 5 segments (or rows in the database)

```
osm_id  |   ref | way(geometry)
--------------------
 1         AA1    ...
 2         AA1    ...
 3         AA1    ...
 4         AA1    ... 
 5         AA1    ...
```

I want a new table where the 5 segments are collapsed into 1, based on their common value in `ref`.

Is this the correct way?

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE ref_roads AS
SELECT ref,
       ST_Multi(ST_Union(f.way)) as the_geom
     FROM planet_osm_roads As f
GROUP BY ref;
```

Comment: Yes. Is there something in the output that makes you doubt it?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Have you tested it?

Comment: How long is it suppose to take on a 400k rows table?

Comment: @Francesco, the time it takes to run the query depends on a few variables and without additional info we cannot really answer that. Have you created indexes on the table? and if you have, on which columns?

Comment: Test with small dataset first or add "limit 100" to your test run.

Answer (score 1):

Your method will work.

You can run this statement to see how many distinct records you have:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT ref) as count_of_ref
FROM planet_osm_roads As f;
```

And compare that count to the number of records in your new table:

```
SELECT Count(ref) as count_of_ref
FROM ref_roads;
```